# Need to install Mercury compiler

Tags: mercury

I need to install Mercury compiler, the link shared on the website of mercury is not found. Could you please share the link to download the mercury compiler.

Comment: http://dl.mercurylang.org/index.html ?

Comment: thanks . I was able to download and unzip the file. However, i could not figure out how to compile and run one of the programs .  it will be very helpful if you could suggest ?

Comment: You should not have received a zip file or archive, but a self-extracting installer. http://dl.mercurylang.org/release/windows/mercury-14.01-vs2013-setup.exe

Comment: Thanks, i was able to install as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Mercury information/documentation page:

https://www.mercurylang.org/download.html

and here is the download page it directs you to with stable releases:

http://dl.mercurylang.org/index.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks . I was able to download and unzip the file. However, i could not figure out how to compile and run one of the programs .  it will be very helpful if you could suggest ?